# How to keep the top-right position of QML item when its size is changing?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I have a toolbar that can be moved (by drag). Depending on the context the content of this toolbar will change, and its size will change accordingly.

My problem is, when the size is changing, the top-left position remains the same and the right border is moving (default and normal behaviour). But I want the top-right position to remain the same and the left border to move instead.

[image: illustration]

From screen 1 to 2 the toolbar gets smaller, and is shown like the blue rectangle. I want it to be placed like the red rectangle.

How can I achieve this ? Without anchoring on the right of the screen, because the toolbar is movable.

Comment: How do you change its width ?

Comment: @GrecKo with a loader different QML files are set, the loader itself is in a Layout and the top Item size is based on `_layout.childrenRect`

Comment: Try `Toolbar.x = (parent.width - toolbar.width - <margin>)`

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that comes to mind would be to wrap the toolbar in an Item, and anchor the toolbar to the top right of the item.

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 800
    height: 800
    visible: true

    Slider {
        id: slider
        value: 200
        to: 400
    }

    Item {
        x: 600

        ToolBar {
            id: toolBar
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right

            implicitWidth: slider.value

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: toolBar.parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Item doesn't render anything itself, and has a "zero" size so that the ToolBar is anchored correctly.

Edit: thanks to @GrecKo for coming up with the MouseArea idea. :) This allows you to drag the ToolBar.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to readjust the position of the item when the `width` changes:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Slider {
        id: slider
        value: 200
        to: 400
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: block
        color: "red"
        width: parseInt(slider.value)
        height:50
        x: 100
        y: 50

        readonly property int previousWidth: width

        onWidthChanged: {
            block.x += previousWidth - width
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: block
        }
    }
}
```

Since `onWidthChanged` is called **before** the `previousWidth` property change,  you can easily adjust the x position from previous and new width values.

(Edit: improved my example using @Mitch Slider)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [`Behavior`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-behavior.html) and [`PropertyAction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-propertyaction.html).
This relies on the feature that you can specify the point in a `Behavior` when its linked property actually change. You can then add some logic before and after this effective change:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 800
    height: 800
    visible: true

    Slider {
        id: slider
        value: 200
        to: 400
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: slider.value
        y: 40
        height: 40
        color: "orange"

        Behavior on width {
            id: behavior
            property real right
            SequentialAnimation {
                ScriptAction { script: behavior.right = rect.x + rect.width } // the width of the rectangle is the old one
                PropertyAction { } // the width of the rectangle changes at this point
                ScriptAction { script: rect.x = behavior.right - rect.width } // the width of the rectangle is the new one
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: parent
        }
    }
}
```